# Why does'nt this simple django code work?

Tags: django

Why doesn't this code work?

```
from django.template import Template,Context
t = Template('Hello , {{name}}')
for name in ('Jack' , 'Sara' , 'John'):
    print t.render(Context({'name' : name}))
```

Comment: It works. 

>>> from django.template import Template, Context
>>> t=Template('Hello,{{name}}')
>>> t
<django.template.base.Template object at 0x16d0ed0>
>>> for name in ('a','b','c'):
...     print t.render(Context({'name':name}))
... 
Hello,a
Hello,b
Hello,c
>>> 
>>> 

Please add the error that you are getting so that we can debug! Thanks.

Comment: The Error is:     IndationError:expected an idented block

Comment: @HamidHoseini Can you post the full code and traceback? There doesn't seem to be any indentation error in the code that you posted in the question.

Answer (score 3):

It does not work if you type this directly in a native Python interpreter session; in fact it raises an `ImproperlyConfigured` exception:

```
In [4]: t = Template('Hello , {{name}}')
ERROR: An unexpected error occurred while tokenizing input
The following traceback may be corrupted or invalid
The error message is: ('EOF in multi-line statement', (38, 0))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImproperlyConfigured                      Traceback (most recent call last)
...

ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting TEMPLATE_DEBUG, but settings are
not configured. You must either define the environment variable
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

On the other hand it does work if you [run your shell session using `django-admin.py` or `manage.py` commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#shell) which correctly load the required settings.

Comment: Good catch. I blindly assumed that the OP would have done 'python manage.py shell'.

Comment: Apprently the OP is receiving some other error. Not this one.

Comment: @AlagappanRamu Indeed; but the code pasted looks like indented properly.

Comment: @HamidHoseini You cannot add screenshots to comments. Please try copying the text and paste it.

Comment: You saw the code.When I run it in manage.py shell,I get this error:                                                                                 File"<console>",line2                                               print t.render(Context({'name':name}))                                     IndationError:expected an idented block

Comment: @HamidHoseini Make sure you have 4 spaces (and no tabs).